# Better way of doing this <tr> ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I am generating from the database a sidebar, based on types of books. For each type, I generate a tab to show listings of books in that type. It works well for other cases with less records, but I am getting a delay of some seconds in this case. Any ideas on how to improve performance of this?

Layout:

```
 @* Sidebar *@
    <div class="col-sm-3" ng-if="ShowSidebar" ngCloak>
        <ul class="list-group sidebar-nav-v1" id="sidebar-nav">
            @* Books *@
            <li class="list-group-item list-toggle">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar-nav" href="#collapse0">
                    <i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-asc"> </i> Books
                </a>
                <ul id="collapse0" class="collapse1 accordion-body collapse">
                    <li ng-repeat="bookTopic in ListBookTopics" style="text-align:justify"><a href="#{{bookTopic.id}}" data-toggle="tab">{{bookTopic.topic_en}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>   @* End of Books *@
            @* Series *@
            <li class="list-group-item list-toggle">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar-nav" href="#collapse1">
                    <i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-asc"> </i> Series (Collections)
                </a>
                <ul id="collapse1" class="collapse">
                    <li ng-repeat="seriesTopic in ListSeriesTopics" style="text-align:justify"><a href="#{{seriesTopic.id}}" data-toggle="tab">{{seriesTopic.topic_en}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>   @* End of Series *@
        </ul> 
    </div>          @* End of Sidebar v2*@

@* Main Area *@
<div class="col-sm-9" ng-if="ShowMainArea" ngCloak>

    <div class="tab-v3">
        <div class="tab-content">
            @* Generate Books Tabs to list books by type *@
            <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="{{booksTopic.id}}" ng-repeat="booksTopic in ListBookTopics" ng-cloak>
                <div class="table-search-v1 panel panel-dark margin-bottom-50">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> {{booksTopic.topic_en}} </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="searchParamBooksTopics">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="center" rowspan="2">Title</th>
                                    <th class="center" rowspan="2">Author</th>
                                    <th class="center" rowspan="1">Number</th>
                                    <th class="center" rowspan="1">Type</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="row in ListBooksInBooks | filter: { title: searchParamBooksTopics }" ng-if="row.title.length>1 && row.topics_id == booksTopic.id">
                                    <td style="text-align:justify;"> {{row.title}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row.author}}</td>
                                    <td class="center">{{row.number}}</td>
                                    <td class="center">{{row.topics_id}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>  @* End of table-responsive *@
                </div>      @* End of table-search-v1 panel panel-dark margin-bottom-50 *@
            </div>          @* End of Tab Content 1 - Books *@

        </div>              @* End of tab-content *@
    </div>                  @* End of tab-v3 *@

</div>                      @* End of col-sm-9 - Main Area *@
```

Angular - Used Lists:

```
$scope.ListBookTopics           = @Html.Raw( new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize( Model.ListBookTopics ) )
$scope.ListBooksInBooks               = @Html.Raw( new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize( Model.ListBooksInBooks ) );
```

The line that is causing the delay is this one:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in ListBooksInBooks | filter: { title: searchParamBooksTopics }" ng-if="row.title.length>1 && row.topics_id == booksTopic.id">
```

Any faster way of looping the list of books and getting all books of that type?

Comment: best optimisation is to use one-way data-binding without watchers, is that possible in your example?

Comment: That is what I am trying to avoid…
Seems like I get little improvement by also adding the topics_id in the filter, but still waiting 2,3 seconds for loading on the page… Any other ideas?

Comment: I would suggest replacing `ng-if` with `ng-show` since it removes DOM, which can be slow, but it also removes the watchers this way, so I don't think it will improve anything. You can also render less with `limitTo`

Comment: Actually ng-if is faster then ng-show, because it removes elements from DOM (in the case books of other types that i won't need while showing a lsiting by a type), while ng-show only hides it by css..
As for render less by use of a limit, is an option..